# Applying functions declared as strings to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to create new columns in the dataframe with 
mathematical functional values of the existing columns.

I know how to do it for simple cases:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Basic dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2], 'col2':[3,5]})
for i in df.columns:
    df[f'{i}_sqrt'] = df[i].apply(lambda x :np.sqrt(x))
```

produces

[image]

Now I want to extend it to the cases where the functions are written as strings like:

```
one_func = ['(x)', '(np.sqrt(x))']
two_func = ['*'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(one_func, one_func)]
```

so that     `two_func = ['(x)*(x)','(x)*(np.sqrt(x))','(np.sqrt(x))*(x)', '(np.sqrt(x))*(np.sqrt(x))']`. Is there any way I can create columns like the first example with these new functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bad design, but I won't go down that road.

Answering your question, you can use `df.eval`

First of all, set

```
one_func = ['{x}', '(sqrt({x}))']
```

with `{}` instead of `()` such that you can replace `{x}` for your actual column name.

Then, for instance,

```
expr = two_func[0].format(x='col1')
df.eval(expr)
```

The food loop your look like

```
for col in df.columns:
    for func in two_func: df[func] = df.eval(func.format(x=col))
```

Comment: I know it is bad, it feels so but I cannot pinpoint the problem. I will be really grateful if you can suggest a better way of doing this.

Comment: Well, design problems are usually posted in [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), so maybe you could give it a go there ;}

Comment: @RafaelC: Pure design questions are off-topic on Code Review. Giving suggestions on how to improve some working piece of code is on-topic (including what a better design for it would be). Have a look at [their off-topic help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), where "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems" is explicitly listed. Those questions might be on-topic on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though.

Comment: @Graipher well this is not a *design* problem per se, but rather a 5 lines of code for loop that needs revision ;} These is no system or architecture in this problem, not even a function or a class ! But thanks for chiming in and contributing ! ;}